# Profiles installed by MDM service are showing as "Not Verified" after upgrading the device to iOS 6

Tags: certificate, mdm, profiles

Profiles installed by MDM service are showing as "Not Verified" after upgrading the device to iOS 6.  These profiles were signed by a InCommon cert issued by AddTrust before being pushed to the devices.  They were showing as "Verified" before the upgrade.  Any ideas what might have caused this?

Answer (score 3):

I got exactly the same problem so it is probably a bug in the iOS profile system because the very same SSL certificate is trusted by the browser.  Note: Our certificate is of the "*.host.org" type.

Comment: Exactly.  I submitted a request with Apple, but haven't heard anything back.

Answer (score 2):

This might be an untrusted CA in the certificate chain from the cert provider you bought it from. Looks like some CAs are untrusted or missing from iOS6. I had the same problem and included the whole of the cert chain in our cert signing bundle and the issue was resolved.
Suggest you open a support case with your cert provider to see if it's a known issue or dig around to see if you can find a list of trusted CAs used in iOS6 - I couldn't find one. Synching the device to iTunes may also refresh the CA list but this didn't work for me this time.

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same problem as your. 
My chain is GeoTrust -> RapidSSL -> MyCert. I have included the full chain in my .crt, but it stills show "not verified" when I try to install the configuration profil.

I don't know how to insert the whole path.

I use an openssl command to sign my file :

openssl smime -sign -signer #{crt_path} -inkey #{private_key_path} -nodetach -outform der -in #{file_to_sign_path} -out #{file_signed_path}

My crt_path is a .crt file, including the three certs.

**EDIT**
I found out the problem with my openssl command. My full chain was in the #{crt_path} but was not used by the command. I added the *-certfile #{crt_path}* and things works well !

Answer (score 2):

Including the intermediate cert in the pkcs7_sign call (php openssl_pkcs7_sign() in my case) revolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Adding the entire path (-root) did the trick.

Verify that the signature created by the MDM SW actually contains the path.  Since it wasn't needed before...